# PHP Curl Proxy Authentication

Tags: php, curl, proxy

i have a html button that made a CURL. When i click this button, is possible to show the browser pop up for the proxy authentication?

I don't want to set the credentials of the proxy in the curl script.

After Marco's advice [https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php]:

Now im trying to ad additional information to the [Pop UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ERV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use this technique:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Then use username and password for proxy authentification.

Comment: Thanks Marco! Do you know how can i edit the authentication pop-up? I want to add a phrase like "Use this user". I'll add an image to my question.